# Power Pivot [365 for Business] - Problems and errors running operations between two different tables

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Good afternoon,

here follows a small simplified model reproducing the problem I am encountering with Power Pivot.

I have a Turnover table that summarizes Turnover values (YTD in a filed, and 2023 Forecast in another field) for each combination of Company/Brand Type/Cluster

[image: TURNOVER Table]

In another Table, for each single Company/Brand/Cluster seen above, I have 4 different percentage Bonuses

[image: Percentage Bonuses]

Then, a third table summarizes a different kind of Bonus, not in percentage but through a fixed una-tantum USD value for each combination seen above

[image]

Here follows the relationships' map

[image]

What I am trying to do, for each combination Company/Brand/Cluster, is to calculate the Total Amount of each one of the four percentage bonuses for each type of turnover value (YTD and Total 2023 Forecast) and in the following screenshot, just for the sake of this example, you see the Calculated Columns I created inside the Turnover Table for just one of the four Bonuses.

[image: data view]

Then I created two Columns that calculate the Missing Turnover to the Forecast in value and in %.
And as regards the % column the problem is the following.

Once I create the Pivot table as per the screenshot below, If I choose a different aggregation level, the % changes and the pivot doesn't run the calculation correctly but does add the single percentages showing an absurd result.

[image]

How can I fix that?

Then, is there a way to avoid creating 3 calculated columns for each single Bonus % and, instead, working with measures?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Mark

Comment: You should clarify in the post precisely which table you are attempting to put the Calculated Column formula in, and also what that formula is.

Comment: I updated the post clarifying the problem. Thanks